# Updating a global variable in xaml c# does not work throughout my project

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I am trying to keep track of a boolean value in my xaml c# phone app project.  The problem I am running to is the global variables get updated but do not carry the value in the project as expected.  I created a class which I invoke in different parts of the project here is my class

```
namespace MathAssistant
{
    public class GlobalVars
    {
        //public static bool DifficultyLevelEasy { get; set; }
        public bool DifficultyLevelInter { get; set; }
        public bool DifficultyLevelDiff { get; set; }

        private bool m_DifficultyLevelEasy = true;

        public bool DifficultyLevelEasy
        {
            get
            {
                return m_DifficultyLevelEasy;
            }
            set
            {
                m_DifficultyLevelEasy = value;
            }

            //public double DivideLeftNumber_2 { get; set; }
            //public double DivideRightNumber_2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried a public static bool and a public bool.  The Static works but I am not able to update its value, the public does not get updated.

Here is how I am trying to update the variable inside my project.

```
private void Easy_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    //get {return GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelEasy;}
   // GlobalVarsDivi.GetType();
    //GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelEasy.GetType();
    //GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelEasy = true; // set the boolean to false
    GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelEasy = true;
    GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelInter = false; // intermediate set to true
    GlobalVarsDivi.DifficultyLevelDiff = false;
}
```

And here is where I am trying to do things based on the value of the variable:

```
// Invoke global vars class
MathAssistant.GlobalVars GlobalVars_ = new MathAssistant.GlobalVars();

// check the status of the checkbox and set the variables here depending on difficulty levels
if (GlobalVars_.DifficultyLevelEasy == true)
{
     do something here
}
```

Can anyone point to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using global variables. Do you need the difficulty in a global context? Otherwise you could carry that information within your form/window.

And instead of having multiple boolean values indicating the difficulty, I'd use an enum (created outside of your class):

```
public enum Difficulty
{
    Easy,
    Intermediate,
    Hard
}
```

Which you can then use in your code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Difficulty _difficulty;

    private void Easy_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _difficulty = Difficulty.Easy;
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (_difficulty == Difficulty.Easy)
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to pass the difficulty to another Window, class or whatever at some later point you should pass it there via a reference. E.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // ...

    private void AtSomeLaterPoint()
    {
        // open another window and pass the difficulty via its constructor
        var otherWindow = new OtherWindow(_difficulty);
        otherWindow.Show();
    }
}

public partial class OtherWindow : Window
{
    private Difficulty _difficulty;

    public OtherWindow(Difficulty difficulty)
    {
        _difficulty = difficulty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense to me.  The plan was to use the level of difficulty in the whole app...  One question I have is do I create the enum in my class?  I will try it Thank you!!

Comment: I made some progress on this but when I try the otherWindow.Show() command I get an error.

Comment: Please create another question with that specific error and post a link to that question here. I'll have a look.